# Qapplication - move to thread doesn't work on Windows

Tags: qt

In main, I'm creating a QApplication in a thread I create, and then, according to commands from the user (from cin), I want to use callbacks on the QApplication instance I created in the thread. 
The creation of the QApllication happens on a workerthread that is called  'StartQtThread', and my main function, in which I get the commands is the main thread.

my problem is that my commands from the main thread, don't work on the qapplication.
for example: if the user enters 'z', I cant to zoom in , on the map in my QApplication. bus since I'm on the main thread nothing happens. 
I tried to use my zoom-in function, from the 'StartQtThread' thread, it works.

tried to use 'moveToThread(qApp->thread())' function from the main thread , but the current thread isn't being changed.

anyone knows how can I change that?

Comment: You can not move GUI objects to different threads.

Comment: thanks @drescherjm but that doesn't make much sense.. all I want is that the triger to a slot will come from cin and not from gui. is it really not possible?

Comment: Why haven't you told it before? Are you allowed to use 3rd party libraries? According to help, qxt's `QxtStdio` does exactly what you need. Link: http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home

Comment: Signals and slots work across threads. Although the handling is not the same. A signal gets pushed to message queue on the target thread instead of direct execution.

Answer (score 1):

`thread->moveToThread(obj)` moves object *obj* to the thread *thread*. Code `moveToThread(qApp->thread())` moves main thread's object to another thread (which is kinda strange). GUI can work ONLY in main thread.